# conditional document: display element if any of the classes match

Tags: css

I have a document and want parts of it to be conditional.  There is one of six classes on the , let's call call them ab cde fghi jklmn opqrst uvwxyz.

The parts that want to be conditional are within  refreences, so the decision has to passed across the boundary in a custom CSS property.

It most attempts at using selector logic resulted in a combinatorial explosion.

I finally hit on a scheme that I thought might work, defining a custom property for each class to be either 0 or 1 at the body, nad then for each element with class cc (as well as some of the other classes), define another custom property to be 0 or 1, and then add up these latter ones and use it as opacity, which, at least in Firefox, doesn't mind if the value exceeds 1.

But EVERYTHING always gets displayed, no matter how I change the body classes. I can't see why a bunch of zeros adds up to opacity of 1!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>conditional text test</title>
<style>
body:not(.ab)
{
--vis-ab:0;
}
body.ab
{
--vis-ab:1;
}
body:not(.cde)
{
--vis-cde:0;
}
body.cde
{
--vis-cde:1;
}
body:not(.fghi)
{
--vis-fghi:0;
}
body.fghi
{
--vis-fghi:1;
}
body:not(.jklmn)
{
--vis-jklmn:0;
}
body.jklmn
{
--vis-jklmn:1;
}
body:not(.opqrst)
{
--vis-opqrst:0;
}
body.opqrst
{
--vis-opqrst:1;
}
body:not(.uvwxyz)
{
--vis-uvwxyz:0;
}
body.uvwxyz
{
--vis-uvwxyz:1;
}

.cc:not(.ab)
{
--has-ab:0;
}
.cc.ab
{
--has-ab:var( --vis-ab );
}
.cc:not(.cde)
{
--has-cde:0;
}
.cc.cde
{
--has-cde:var( --vis-cde );
}
.cc:not(.fghi)
{
--has-fghi:0;
}
.cc.fghi
{
--has-fghi:var( --vis-fghi );
}
.cc:not(.jklmn)
{
--has-jklmn:0;
}
.cc.jklmn
{
--has-jklmn:var( --vis-jklmn );
}
.cc:not(.opqrst)
{
--has-opqrst:0;
}
.cc.opqrst
{
--has-opqrst:var( --vis-opqrst );
}
.cc:not(.uvwxyz)
{
--has-uvwxyz:0;
}
.cc.uvwxyz
{
--has-uvwxyz:var( --vis-uvwxyz );
}
.cc
{
opacity:calc( var( --has-ab ) + var( --has-cde ) + var( --has-fghi ) + var( --has-jklmn ) + var ( --has-opqrst ) + var( --has-uvwxyz ));
}
</style>
</head>
<body class=ab>
<h1>conditional text test</h1>
<div>
<span class="cc ab">ab</span>
<span class="cc cde">cde</span>
<span class="cc fghi">fghi</span>
<span class="cc jklmn">jklmn</span>
<span class="cc opqrst">opqrst</span>
<span class="cc uvwxyz">uvwxyz</span>
</div>
<div class="cc ab fghi">ab or fghi</div>
<div class="cc ab uvwxyz">ab or uvwxyz</div>
<div class="cc opqrst fghi">opqrst or fghi</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there cannot be a space between var and the open (. I have one in that opacity calculation above.